# Должен ли каждый микросервис работать на своем порту

Tags: микросервисы

Есть например проект, в нем например 5 микросервисов, которые между собой как-то работают, вопрос, должен ли микросервис работать каждый на своем порту, например:

1. Авторизация = 5001
2. Покупка = 5002
3. Отчеты = 5003

Comment: А что, есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: Вы же не сможете запустить их на одной машине с одним и тем же портом... и чем это вообще мешать может? Количество свободных портов более чем достаточное.